# Each instance is executing code when using fragment.newInstance()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a single activity and multiple fragments and I'm using `newInstance()` to create/switch among fragments.
If I open a fragment by clicking to navigation menu or by another fragment, it creates new instance each time.
Let's say if I open fragment A which has method `getData(args)` then this instance and all previous instances of fragment A call `getData(args)`, making unwanted requests and load to server.

I'm also using `registerReceiver()` and `sendBroadcast()` methods of `LocalBroadCastManager` instance and code inside them is executing number of times equal to number of fragment instances which I can see in Logcat.

What I'm doing wrong or how to deal with this issue? Should I use `fragment()` instead of new instance or something else? If any code require from my side then let me also know.